# How to read the text box values?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am new to this ios development. In my first journey, I am trying to develope a login application on ios. Regarding this, I have created a UI with two labels and two text boxes and one button.

I have the method 'login'.

My requirement is after entering the values in text boxes, if I click on 'login' button then in the 'login' method I have to read the two values which are entered in the text box and validate the authontication(hard coded) and forward to success view.

Please give me this example.

Thanks & Regards,
Syed

Comment: "I can haz teh codez" - Hmm, I've heard this before...

Comment: poor question. why dont you start by showing us the code you have done so far. If you have none, then google some tutorials or get on youTube - there is loads out there for new developers. I am completely self-taught, mainly through youTube tutorials, googling stuff and the occasional book.... no one on here is gonna go out there way and write your app for you

Answer (score 10):

Get the text inside the text field using the text property

```
NSString *name = yourNameField.text;
```